# PHP Yii2 Sorting data without difference in first letters?

Tags: php, yii2

I was wonder if it's possible to sort data by letters, but no difference in first and second letters?

Like datas in my DB are:
ideapad
Thinkpad
A1278
Inspirion

If i sort this the ideapad goes last, and sort like this:

A1278
Inspirion
Thinkpad
ideapad

I mean I have the sorting code which works as default in my controller but how can I add to not make difference between lowercase and uppercase ?:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new ModellSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder = ['nev' => SORT_ASC];

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: You mean you want a case insensitive search.

Comment: Change your database collation to `utf8_general_ci`